# How do you render an alternative view at runtime with Playframework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

Based on the presence of a query parameter, I would like to render a JSON view of my data, instead of the default html view. What is the best way to achieve this globally accross all templates?

e.g, instead of

```
def index = Action {
  val foo = getFoo()
  Ok(views.html.index(foo))
}
```

I woud like to optionally display a Jsonified version of foo (using Gson or similar library). This will be particularly useful for front-end developers who just want to view all available data rather than rely on code completion (as is possible in our current custom framework).

I've looked at filters and action compostion, but don't seem to have access to the raw parameters of the view.

Edit: In Spring MVC, this would be implemented using a ViewResolver, and a custom spring View which implements the following method

```
void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
```

and turning model into JSON is then straightforward ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to use a custom view, I did create a custom template which does a console.log of the json view of the data

```
@(any: Any, name: String = "json")
@import services.Serializers.gson

@if(play.Play.isDev){
    <script type="application/javascript">
    var json=@Html(gson.toJson(any));
    console.log("@name: " , json);
    </script>
}
```

I used a custom gson serializer defined here: https://gist.github.com/raelg/e12d731ba01ba58f0006